# Kenmore refrigerator Mo # 25361122101 - how to find out volume

Tags: refrigerator

My refrigerator died today and I am about to get replacement, but for some reason I cannot find out anywhere the volume of refrigerator. Here are details Kenmore model number 25361122101. It looks like 20 cubic feet. Any suggestion where to look?

Comment: Usually what **actually matters** is "what are the outside dimension constraints of the spot in your kitchen to put a refrigerator?" rather than the particular cubic foot size rating, anyway...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look on your calculator after multiplying the inside height by the inside width by the inside depth, all in inches and then dividing that number by 1728 cu in / ft.  Do freezer and lower unit separately for more accurate figure.